# Jquery How to output individual json values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the individual json values and output the values in the format below. 
Its not returning  any individual values currently.

How can I output all the individual values correctly?

My example is here [Jquery with JSON fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/zttgp2L5/11/)
for example

```
console.log(" nestedValue  name" + nestedKey + "--------" + nestedValue.name);
console.log(" nestedValue shortURL" + nestedKey + "---------" + nestedValue.shortURL);
console.log(" nestedValue parenthicalCategory1" + nestedKey + "---------" + nestedValue.parenthicalCategory1);
console.log(" nestedValue parenthicalCategory2" + nestedKey + "---------" + nestedValue.parenthicalCategory2);
console.log(" nestedValue keyword" + nestedKey + "---------" + nestedValue.keyword);
console.log(" nestedValue shortDesc" + nestedKey + "---------" + nestedValue.shortDesc);
console.log(" nestedValue isRenew" + nestedKey + "---------" + nestedValue.isRenew);
console.log(" nestedValue isApply" + nestedKey + "---------" + nestedValue.isApply);
```

JavaScript

```
var  jsonVals='';
jQuery.each(jsonObject, function(key, value) {

    if(key == "filters")
    {
        jQuery.each(value, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
        {
            var objectKey = Object.keys(nestedValue)[0];
            var objectVal = eval("nestedValue['"+objectKey+"']");
            //console.log(eval("nestedValue['"+objectKey+"']"));
            $("#filters").append(objectKey + '------------' +  objectVal + '<br/>' );
        });

    }

    if(key == "data")
    {
        jQuery.each(value, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
        {
            jQuery.each(nestedValue.azIndexDescPages, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
            {


                jQuery.each(nestedValue, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
                {   
                     console.log(nestedValue);
                ///$("#data").append(nestedKey + '------------' +  nestedValue + '<br/>' );

                    /////////////////////////////////////////

jsonVals +='<div class="id" >nestedValue  guid ' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.guid+'</div>';
jsonVals +='<div class="name">nestedValue  name' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.name +'</div>';
jsonVals +='<div class="url"> nestedValue shortURL' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.shortURL+'</div>';
jsonVals +='<div class="keyword"> nestedValue keyword' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.keyword+'</div>';
jsonVals += '<div class="desc">nestedValue shortDesc' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.shortDesc+'</div>';
jsonVals +='<div class="renew"> nestedValue isRenew' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.isRenew+'</div>';




                    //////////////////////////////////////////

                });





            });



                // $("#data").append('<br /><br />');
               $("#data").append(jsonVals);

        });

    }
});
```

Comment: YOu should loop through it, and then use it just like any other object.[objectName].[proprtyName]. I would use a for(var loop. If you need an example I can post one. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Also, the nested objects are collections, so you have to itterate them to, according to what I see in the fiddle. It is kind of not enough information though on what exactly is the issue your having.

Comment: really confusing when you name all the nested  `each` arguments the same. Try scaling this down to less html parsing and more to do with the looping first

Comment: I am trying to get the individual values nestedValue.name, nestedValue.shortURL etc currently it ruturns undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third iteration of jQuery.each is now down to the property level of the azIndexDescPages object. so back up one iteration: http://jsfiddle.net/zttgp2L5/14/

```
    if(key == "data")
    {
        jQuery.each(value, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
        {
            jQuery.each(nestedValue.azIndexDescPages, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
            {
                 console.log(nestedValue);
                        jsonVals +='<div class="id" >nestedValue  guid ' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.guid+'</div>';
                        jsonVals +='<div class="name">nestedValue  name' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.name +'</div>';
                        jsonVals +='<div class="url"> nestedValue shortURL' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.shortURL+'</div>';
                        jsonVals +='<div class="keyword"> nestedValue keyword' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.keyword+'</div>';
                        jsonVals += '<div class="desc">nestedValue shortDesc' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.shortDesc+'</div>';
                        jsonVals +='<div class="renew"> nestedValue isRenew' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue.isRenew+'</div>';
           });

       });

       $("#data").append(jsonVals);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks is close to waht  I was looking for  but i noticed i ur code is giving duplicates ..

Comment: I edited my answer. It was the placement of $('#data').append(jsonVals); It has to be just before the closing bracket of your if statement and outside both each loops.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is that you are not able to get all traversing nesed objects in the json, this type of function should work, and lead you in correct direction.

```
function loop(obj) {
$.each(obj, function(key, val) {
    if(val && typeof val === "object") { // object, call recursively          
        loop(val);
    } else {
            KEY: VAL
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace your code with this:

```
//CODE
var jsonVals='';
jQuery.each(jsonObject, function(key, value) {
  if(key == "filters")
  {
    jQuery.each(value, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
  {
    var objectKey = Object.keys(nestedValue)[0];
    var objectVal = eval("nestedValue['"+objectKey+"']");
    //console.log(eval("nestedValue['"+objectKey+"']"));
    $("#filters").append(objectKey + '------------' +  objectVal + '<br/>' );
    });
  }
  if(key == "data")
  {
    jQuery.each(value, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
    {
      jQuery.each(nestedValue.azIndexDescPages, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
        {
          jQuery.each(nestedValue, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
          { 
            $("#data").append('<div class="id" >nestedValue  ' + nestedKey + '--------' + nestedValue+'</div><br>');
        });
      });             
    });
  }
});
//CODE
```